# Docker version supported in Kubernetes 1.8

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm going to upgrade my Kubernetes cluster to the version `1.8.7`. Does anybody know which docker version is best compatible with it?

This is what I found on the Kubernetes official page, but I suppose it might be for the latest k8s release (`1.9`)?

> On each of your machines, install Docker. Version v1.12 is
>   recommended, but v1.11, v1.13 and 17.03 are known to work as well.
>   Versions 17.06+ might work, but have not yet been tested and verified
>   by the Kubernetes node team.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [kubernetes v1.8.0 changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.8.md/#external-dependencies)

> Continuous integration builds use Docker versions 1.11.2, 1.12.6, 1.13.1, and 17.03.2. These versions were validated on Kubernetes 1.8.

So any of these version should work fine.